# Handling percentage sign in url

Tags: python, http, cherrypy

I've got an app that processes GET requests. I read a variable that holds a pattern for querying using `%` as wildcard. So if URL contains `patt=M%` I'm fetching all names starting with `M`. All worked fine till I tried to use `%D0` as a search pattern. I get the following error:

`The given query string could not be processed. Query strings for this resource must be encoded with 'utf8'.`

As I've found out using https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp, the `%D0` string is being treated as a code for non-unicode character.

Now the question is: How to handle such patterns as `%D0`? In other words: how to treat this as three characters without encoding?

One workaround I've found so far is to use `%25` instead of `%`, like using `patt=%25D` - but I'd need to actually *handle* the requests.

EDIT:
Here's an example. Let's take the basic cherrpy example from [tutorial](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-1-a-basic-web-application). I've just modified it to handle `params` and return the value of `myvar`:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, **params):
        #return "Hello world!"
        return cherrypy.request.params['myVar']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Once it's running you may open the url - by default it should start on http://localhost:8080/?myVar=blahblahblah

It opens a page and returns the myVar value: blahblahblah

Now, try http://localhost:8080/?myVar=%D0

This will cause an error I'd like to prevent.

Of course http://localhost:8080/?myVar=%25D0 works fine and shows the `%D0`.

Comment: It's working as intended. all urlencoded URI parts are automatically decoded by cherrypy and then passed to your handler. Normally browsers urlencode URLs automatically as well. So I'm not sure what you are asking for. If you have custom client, you should of course encode url as appropriate.

Comment: The goal was to put the required mask directly in the browser address bar. No custom client, just Chrome, Firefox or any other browser. But now I start to think this is simply not possible and I's need to add a textbox that I'll then encode myself and redirect...

Comment: Do you mean user would manually enter your query in the address bar? If you have a form with an input it should be encoded automatically.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to say: putting the query mask directly in browser address bar. I do think of creating a form for it since I can't have it done this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **quote** method to handle those characters in url as follows:

```
import urllib
print urllib.quote("patt=M%")
```

Comment: I've improved my question a bit with a code sample. It's not using urllib. Please take a look.